# AWS lambda what policy to add so I can call an API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a lambda that calls an API, but need to configure it so it can resolve DNS,
how do I enable port 53 and UDP?

```
var https = require('https');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var params = {
        host: "bittrex.com",
        path: "/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries"
    };
    var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
        let data = '';
        console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            console.log("DONE");
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });
    req.end();
};
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the AWS Lambda function is connected to a VPC? If not, then simply disconnect it and it will have access to the Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Lambda running inside a VPC

If your lambda is running inside a VPC, you can verify if you have permissions to access VPC settings, have a look at `AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole` policy:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#policies/arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

```yaml
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
                "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
                "ec2:AssignPrivateIpAddresses",
                "ec2:UnassignPrivateIpAddresses"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ensure your security group and network access control list allow inbound and outbound access to the address/range.

#### Lambda is not running inside a VPC

If your lambda is not running inside a VPC and you are still encountering issues, you can try to use Node.js `dns` module to perform DNS resolution manually:

```js
var dns = require('dns');

dns.lookup('example.com', function(err, addresses, family) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    callback(err);
  } else {
    console.log('IP addresses:', addresses);
    callback(null, addresses);
  }
});
```

This can provide you a starting point to debug it